# Почему не выравнивается по вертикали?

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Почему не выравнивается по вертикали текст в `TextEdit`? Я пытался вировнять по вертикале методом `setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter)`. По горизонтале выравнивается методом `setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter)`.

Answer (score 1):

Из описания метода [`setAlignment()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setAlignment) класса `QTextEdit` (в переводе):

> Допустимые значения выравнивания - `Qt::AlignLeft`, `Qt::AlignRight`, `Qt::AlignJustify` и `Qt::AlignCenter` (**центрирует по горизонтали**).

Центрирование по вертикали отсутствует.

Можете использовать `QLineEdit`, если допустимо:

```
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit("Текст");
lineEdit->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Comment: а мне нужно чтобы центрировалося по вертикале и горизонтале. Другого виджета  я не видел, которий бы решил мою проблему. Может  можно как-то обойти это задание?

Comment: Наследоваться от `QTextEdit` и в ручную заниматься отрисовкой элемента.